# Call if conditions from another cell in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, if-this-then-that

I want to define conditions in cell values and pass them in if statements in google spreadsheets.
This is a simple formula how this can be achieved normally

[image: This is simple formula how this can be achieved normally]

This is what I am trying to achieve. Instead of formula in 1st parameter in if function, I am setting this condition in one cell value and passing that cell value in if condition parameter.

[image]

The reason behind this is, I am having multiple conditions that I need to pass in if statements, so defining in different cells will be more manageable.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

What you should have in cell would be:

```
=AND(H31>35,H32>35,H33>35)
```

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.